# how to convert a string into dictionary in python?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a string:

```
a = subteam3=zzz&comments3=good&subteam9=yyy&comments9=bad
```

its passed from Ajax to Django:

```
a = request.POST.get('a')
```

and i have done `a = urllib2.unquote(a)` to convert it into a proper string.

I want to convert it to 2 dictionaries:

```
subteam = { 3 : zzz, 9 : yyy }

comments = { 3 : good, 9 : bad }
```

Can any one give me a solution?

Comment: Where is your attempt, and what precisely is the problem with it? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to decode HTML form values. Look at Pythons cgi module.

Comment: yes they are form values.. i passed it in ajax as data: { a : $('form#form').serialize() }

Comment: Why not use django forms as they are intended?

Comment: got the answer..thank u all !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 'subteam3=zzz&comments3=good&subteam9=yyy&comments9=bad'
a = a.split('&')
b = dict()
c = dict()

for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if 'subteam' in a[i]:
        temp,temp1 = a[i].strip('subteam').split("=")
        b[temp]=temp1
    else:
        temp,temp1 = a[i].strip('comments').split("=")
        c[temp]=temp1

print b,c
```

Answer (score 0):

The `request.POST` and `request.GET` are dicts already (actually, dict like).

Check this part of the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

They act like this object, from Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

You can do, something like:

```
a = request.POST.get("a", None);
if a:
    print a
else:
    print "no a"
```

If you need to process this information, that looks like a Django model, or whatever, checkout Django forms. You can create a django form from a POST request, regardless if it's AJAX or not, and let it do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'subteam3=zzz&comments3=good&subteam9=yyy&comments9=bad'
subteam = {}
comment = {}

for each in a.split('&'):
    if each.startswith('subteam'):
        subteam[each.split('=')[0][-1]]=each.split('=')[1]
    elif each.startswith('comment'):
        comment[each.split('=')[0][-1]]=each.split('=')[1]
```